# Cannot compile example code in libpca

Tags: linux, gcc, dll, environment-variables, undefined-reference

I'm trying to install the [libpca](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpca/files/) package.
I've already have Armadillo set up.

The libpca package is unzipped to `/my/dir/`. And I set the `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` and other variables to the place Armadillo installed.  (`export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/my/dir/arma_install/include/:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`)

I run the following command to install libpca:

```
/my/dir/libpca-1.3.3$  ./configure --prefix=/my/dir/libpca-1.3.3
/my/dir/libpca-1.3.3$  make
```

which has warnings but no error. And the command:

```
/my/dir/libpca-1.3.3$  make install prefix=/my/dir/libpca-1.3.3
```

It seems good and no error is reported.

Then I try to compile and run the example file in `/my/dir/libpca-1.3.3/examples/simple/pca_example.cpp`. In dir `examples`, I run

```
/my/dir/libpca-1.3.3/examples$  make
```

It returns

> make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'
>
> make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'

And no new file is created. Then I cd into `examples/simple`, and run

```
/my/dir/libpca-1.3.3/examples/simple$  make
```

It returns:

> make: Nothing to be done for 'all'

And no new file is created. Then I run

```
/my/dir/libpca-1.3.3/examples/simple$  make check
```

It returns the following errors:

The variables `wrapper_dsyev_`, `wrapper_dgemv_`, `wrapper_dgemm_`, etc. in the errors above, exist in the following binaries:

```
/my/dir/arma_install/lib64/libarmadillo.so.8.500.0
/my/dir/arma_downloaded/CMakeFiles/armadillo.dir/src/wrapper.cpp.o
/my/dir/arma_downloaded/CMakeFiles/CMakeRelink.dir/libarmadillo.so.8.500.0
```

After I `export` them into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, the same errors are still returned.

I think there should be something wrong with the include path, and environment variables. How do I solve it?

Moreover, if I need to write code in `/my/dir/working_dir/`, how can I set the path?

----------------------------------edited below--------------------

When I made the update described below, at step 3:

```
/my/dir/libpca-1.3.3$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/dir/arma_install/lib64 make check
```

It returns the following errors:

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/dir/arma_install/lib64/  make check
>
> Making check in src/lib
>
> make[1]: Entering directory `/my/dir/libpca-1.3.3/src/lib'
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/my/dir/libpca-1.3.3/src/lib'
>
> Making check in test
>
> make[1]: Entering directory `/my/dir/libpca-1.3.3/test'
>
> make  unittest
>
> make[2]: Entering directory `/my/dir/libpca-1.3.3/test'
>
> /bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -I../src/lib
>   -pthread -O2    -o unittest main.o testcases.o test_pca.o test_utils.o ../src/lib/.libs/libpca.a  -L/my/dir/source_scripts/lib64
>
> libtool: link: g++ -I../src/lib -pthread -O2 -o unittest main.o
>   testcases.o test_pca.o test_utils.o  ../src/lib/.libs/libpca.a
>   -L/my/dir/arma_install/lib64 -pthread
>
> test_utils.o: In function `void arma::glue_times::apply, arma::Mat
>
> > (arma::Mat&, arma::Mat const&, arma::Mat const&, double)':
>
> test_utils.cpp:(.text.hot._ZN4arma10glue_times5applyIdLb1ELb0ELb1ENS_3MatIdEES3_EEvRNS2_IT_EERKT3_RKT4_S4_[_ZN4arma10glue_times5applyIdLb1ELb0ELb1ENS_3MatIdEES3_EEvRNS2_IT_EERKT3_RKT4_S4_]+0x169):
>   undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemm_'
>
> test_utils.cpp:(.text.hot._ZN4arma10glue_times5applyIdLb1ELb0ELb1ENS_3MatIdEES3_EEvRNS2_IT_EERKT3_RKT4_S4_[_ZN4arma10glue_times5applyIdLb1ELb0ELb1ENS_3MatIdEES3_EEvRNS2_IT_EERKT3_RKT4_S4_]+0x363):
>   undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemv_'
>
> test_utils.cpp:(.text.hot._ZN4arma10glue_times5applyIdLb1ELb0ELb1ENS_3MatIdEES3_EEvRNS2_IT_EERKT3_RKT4_S4_[_ZN4arma10glue_times5applyIdLb1ELb0ELb1ENS_3MatIdEES3_EEvRNS2_IT_EERKT3_RKT4_S4_]+0x45c):
>   undefined reference to `wrapper_dsyrk_'
>
> ../src/lib/.libs/libpca.a(pca.o): In function
>   `stats::pca::bootstrap_eigenvalues_()':
>
> pca.cpp:(.text+0x454d): undefined reference to `wrapper_dsyev_'
>
> pca.cpp:(.text+0x4953): undefined reference to `wrapper_dsyevd_'
>
> ../src/lib/.libs/libpca.a(pca.o): In function `bool
>   arma::auxlib::eig_sym_dc
>
> > (arma::Col&, arma::Mat&, arma::Base > const&)':
>
> pca.cpp:(.text._ZN4arma6auxlib10eig_sym_dcIdNS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS_3ColIT_EERNS2_IS5_EERKNS_4BaseIS5_T0_EE[_ZN4arma6auxlib10eig_sym_dcIdNS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS_3ColIT_EERNS2_IS5_EERKNS_4BaseIS5_T0_EE]+0x13a):
>   undefined reference to `wrapper_dsyevd_'
>
> ../src/lib/.libs/libpca.a(pca.o): In function `bool
>   arma::eig_sym
>
> > (arma::Col::pod_type>&, arma::Mat::elem_type>&,
> >     arma::Base::elem_type, arma::Mat > const&,
> >     char const*,
> >     arma::arma_blas_type_only::elem_type>::result
> >     const*)':
>
> pca.cpp:(.text._ZN4arma7eig_symINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS_3ColINT_8pod_typeEEERNS1_INS4_9elem_typeEEERKNS_4BaseIS8_S4_EEPKcPKNS_19arma_blas_type_onlyIS8_E6resultE[_ZN4arma7eig_symINS_3MatIdEEEEbRNS_3ColINT_8pod_typeEEERNS1_INS4_9elem_typeEEERKNS_4BaseIS8_S4_EEPKcPKNS_19arma_blas_type_onlyIS8_E6resultE]+0x1a0):
>   undefined reference to `wrapper_dsyev_'
>
> ../src/lib/.libs/libpca.a(pca.o): In function `double
>   arma::auxlib::det_lapack(arma::Mat const&, bool)':
>
> pca.cpp:(.text._ZN4arma6auxlib10det_lapackIdEET_RKNS_3MatIS2_EEb[_ZN4arma6auxlib10det_lapackIdEET_RKNS_3MatIS2_EEb]+0x117):
>   undefined reference to `wrapper_dgetrf_'
>
> ../src/lib/.libs/libpca.a(pca.o): In function `void arma::gemv::apply_blas_type >(double*,
>   arma::Mat const&, double const*, double, double)':
>
> pca.cpp:(.text._ZN4arma4gemvILb1ELb0ELb0EE15apply_blas_typeIdNS_3MatIdEEEEvPT_RKT0_PKS5_S5_S5_[_ZN4arma4gemvILb1ELb0ELb0EE15apply_blas_typeIdNS_3MatIdEEEEvPT_RKT0_PKS5_S5_S5_]+0x86):
>   undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemv_'
>
> ../src/lib/.libs/libpca.a(pca.o): In function `void arma::gemv::apply_blas_type >(double*,
>   arma::Mat const&, double const*, double, double)':
>
> pca.cpp:(.text._ZN4arma4gemvILb0ELb0ELb0EE15apply_blas_typeIdNS_3MatIdEEEEvPT_RKT0_PKS5_S5_S5_[_ZN4arma4gemvILb0ELb0ELb0EE15apply_blas_typeIdNS_3MatIdEEEEvPT_RKT0_PKS5_S5_S5_]+0x86):
>   undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemv_'
>
> ../src/lib/.libs/libpca.a(pca.o): In function `void
>   arma::glue_times::apply, arma::Mat >(arma::Mat&,
>   arma::Mat const&, arma::Mat const&, double)':
>
> pca.cpp:(.text.hot._ZN4arma10glue_times5applyIdLb0ELb0ELb0ENS_3MatIdEES3_EEvRNS2_IT_EERKT3_RKT4_S4_[_ZN4arma10glue_times5applyIdLb0ELb0ELb0ENS_3MatIdEES3_EEvRNS2_IT_EERKT3_RKT4_S4_]+0x129):
>   undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemm_'
>
> pca.cpp:(.text.hot._ZN4arma10glue_times5applyIdLb0ELb0ELb0ENS_3MatIdEES3_EEvRNS2_IT_EERKT3_RKT4_S4_[_ZN4arma10glue_times5applyIdLb0ELb0ELb0ENS_3MatIdEES3_EEvRNS2_IT_EERKT3_RKT4_S4_]+0x334):
>   undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemv_'
>
> ../src/lib/.libs/libpca.a(pca.o): In function `void
>   arma::glue_times::apply,
>   arma::Mat >(arma::Mat&, arma::Mat const&,
>   arma::Mat const&, double)':
>
> pca.cpp:(.text.hot._ZN4arma10glue_times5applyIdLb0ELb1ELb0ENS_3MatIdEES3_EEvRNS2_IT_EERKT3_RKT4_S4_[_ZN4arma10glue_times5applyIdLb0ELb1ELb0ENS_3MatIdEES3_EEvRNS2_IT_EERKT3_RKT4_S4_]+0x14a):
>   undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemm_'
>
> pca.cpp:(.text.hot._ZN4arma10glue_times5applyIdLb0ELb1ELb0ENS_3MatIdEES3_EEvRNS2_IT_EERKT3_RKT4_S4_[_ZN4arma10glue_times5applyIdLb0ELb1ELb0ENS_3MatIdEES3_EEvRNS2_IT_EERKT3_RKT4_S4_]+0x33c):
>   undefined reference to `wrapper_dsyrk_'
>
> ../src/lib/.libs/libpca.a(utils.o): In function
>   `stats::utils::compute_column_rms(arma::Mat const&)':
>
> utils.cpp:(.text+0xe95): undefined reference to `wrapper_ddot_'
>
> ../src/lib/.libs/libpca.a(utils.o): In function `void
>   arma::glue_times::apply,
>   arma::Mat >(arma::Mat&, arma::Mat const&,
>   arma::Mat const&, double)':
>
> utils.cpp:(.text.hot._ZN4arma10glue_times5applyIdLb1ELb0ELb0ENS_3MatIdEES3_EEvRNS2_IT_EERKT3_RKT4_S4_[_ZN4arma10glue_times5applyIdLb1ELb0ELb0ENS_3MatIdEES3_EEvRNS2_IT_EERKT3_RKT4_S4_]+0x353):
>   undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemm_'
>
> utils.cpp:(.text.hot._ZN4arma10glue_times5applyIdLb1ELb0ELb0ENS_3MatIdEES3_EEvRNS2_IT_EERKT3_RKT4_S4_[_ZN4arma10glue_times5applyIdLb1ELb0ELb0ENS_3MatIdEES3_EEvRNS2_IT_EERKT3_RKT4_S4_]+0x8a4):
>   undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemv_'
>
> utils.cpp:(.text.hot._ZN4arma10glue_times5applyIdLb1ELb0ELb0ENS_3MatIdEES3_EEvRNS2_IT_EERKT3_RKT4_S4_[_ZN4arma10glue_times5applyIdLb1ELb0ELb0ENS_3MatIdEES3_EEvRNS2_IT_EERKT3_RKT4_S4_]+0x9ab):
>   undefined reference to `wrapper_dsyrk_'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make[2]: *** [unittest] Error 1
>
> make[2]: Leaving directory `/my/dir/libpca-1.3.3/test'
>
> make[1]: *** [check-am] Error 2
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/my/dir/libpca-1.3.3/test'
>
> make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1

What should I do next?

Comment: Didn't work with these tools but seems like what you did for include files `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/my/dir/arma_install/include/...` (required at *compile* time) you have to do for libraries as well `CPLUS_LIBRARY_PATH` or smth similar, check the docs (required at *link* time).

Comment: After your update the linker still cannot find the armadillo library. Are you sure you passed the correct paths to `configure`? Also, make sure you built armadillo correctly. If you could paste your exact command sequence for building both armadillo and libpca that'd be useful.

Comment: You are correct. It turns out I need to set the `arma` path before I run the `./configure` command. Now the `pca_example` can compile and run. One last question, Now I move the `pca_example.cpp` together with the `Makefile` to `/my/dir/`, i.e. the prefix argument passed to `./configure`. when I run make command, it returns "Makefile:354 .deps/pca_example.Po: No such file or directory". What dependency or path do I need to set if I wish to write code in a customized directory?

Comment: You can’t just move the Makefile to a new directory and expect it to work. What I would recommend is for you to create a new project in your IDE (e.g. Eclipse). There you can then set libpca as a library your project depends on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the linker of the location of your armadillo library. You can achieve this in two ways:

1. Through environment variable: `export LIBRARY_PATH=/arma/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH`
2. Passing armadillo include and library path to configure directly:
   `./configure --with-armadillo-incdir=/arma/include --with-armadillo-libdir=/arma/lib`

I would recommend using option 2 as it prevents settings up extra environment variables which may pollute, well, your environment.

Note that `--prefix` denotes the directory in which libpca is being installed to. This should be different from the source directory!

After configure you can run `make`, `make check`, and `make install`. For `make check` to succeed the linux library loader needs to know the location of the armadillo shared library. So one option is to run like so: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/arma/lib make check`

To summarize the commands you need to run:

1. `./configure --prefix=/libpca/install --with-armadillo-incdir=/arma/include --with-armadillo-libdir=/arma/lib`
2. `make`
3. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/arma/lib make check`
4. `make install`

Obviously, you need to adjust the paths to your situation.

Caveat: On some platforms you need to explicitly link with lapack and blas. So if you run into further linker errors then try configuring like this:
`LIBS='-llapack -lblas' ./configure --prefix=/libpca/install --with-armadillo-incdir=/arma/include --with-armadillo-libdir=/arma/lib`